# Cardinal or ordinal number for the name of the school

Tags: word-choice

The offcial name of the school up to this day has been: Tallinn School No 21. Does it sound correct and formal Br Eng?

Now it has been proposed that it should be Tallinn 21st School. Is there a difference? For us it sounds wrong because the ordinal number refers to ranking or order, doesn’t it?

Comment: I don't think that anybody will read that as the 21st _best_ school (ie, that there are 20 better ones), if that is your point. If anything, people may think that is was the 21st school to be established in Tallinn. (Which is what I would think, although I can imagine the number having come about in a different way. Maybe it had number 21 in some plans. Or got arbitrarily number 21 when they thought of numbering schools.)

Comment: No. 21 is better than 21st. For reference, in New York public schools are abbreviated as PS and have numbers, which is not unlike the system you have, for example PS 157, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_public_elementary_schools_in_New_York_City

Comment: Standard rules do not necessarily apply to names & titles. Tallinn is in Estonia (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tallinn_School_No._21), so why should British English rules apply? Finally, any answer to you question will be primarily an opinion, rather than based on rules of grammar, and therefore the question is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Numbered schools sound odd to British ears anyway because British schools are usually named. The names can be the name of the community they serve, the road they are on, the name of the founder, the name of a famous person or something else. To us schools with numbers sound Soviet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one right answer. When translating we usually try to copy the original. I have never heard of an ordinal being used in this context in a translation from any language.

But if you did want to use an ordinal, 21st Tallinn School is the standard English grammar since we mean the 21st of all the Tallinn schools not the Tallinn school amongst all the 21st schools.

This is what we see when we do use ordinals in this sort of situation, e.g. for [military units](https://www.heraldry-wiki.com/heraldrywiki/index.php?title=21st_Airborne_Division_(Phantom_Unit),_US_Army).